# How to remove REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES from previous verison

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, publish, google-play-console

In previous version of my app I used open_file and unfortunately it used REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission.
Now I delete this permission and changed package now Im using open_filex.
Added this code to my manifest file.

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:node="remove"/>
```

But can not publish my new version. Google wants me fill the "Sensitive permissions and APIs" - part witch I don't now what case I should to choose.
How can I solve this problem ?

[image]

[image]

I also tried to add new release in Internal testing but couldn't
[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue, cant' publish new version because of the previous one

Comment: My steps :
1. if you have open_file package remove and install other one, 
2. search in your merge_file do there any REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission and check from where and remove. 
3. then in your googleconsole you need to fill datacollection side and also why your app is using REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES - permission side. I also upload a video why i was using it. 
4. Then change version in internal testing. 
5. then you can publish your app. Good luck

Comment: I could send to review the new release only after filling the datacollection form. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i solved changing the plugin for this:

[open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex)

This package is a fork of open_file to fix the following issues:

-Remove REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission in Android to comply with GooglePlay publish policies

Comment: after change it, you also removed that: `<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:node="remove"/>` ?

Comment: I checked every version. This appears because of my previous version

Answer (score 0):

Remove that code from AndroidManifest. Not required.

Alternatively check if the new package you added contains the permission.

[open_file_safe](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file_safe) worked for me.

Comment: open_filex also working fine, I added new pictures about my problem

Comment: does the app version in **Internal Testing** track have the implementation of the old package? Do check and push update in that track first and then push same to production.

Comment: yes, I just need create new release in Internal testing??

Comment: Yes... Then it should get accepted.

Comment: I got the same warning message. I attached picture , what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Go to app content and submit sensitive permissions for now... then once accepted you can remove it and push update...

Comment: it needs Video instructions, that's why searching another way

Comment: hope there is.... I can't remember if I did that :(

Comment: yeah, starting 31.01.23 we should complete declaration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251595/discussion-between-lala-naibova-and-clevino-alrin).

Comment: can you add ss of the error section in console?

Answer (score 0):

I got this message from Google support.

Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support and we apologize for not addressing your query as quickly as expected. We are currently experiencing a huge inflow of support requests which caused the delay in responding to your email.

Your app com.copafacil is not compliant with the Permissions policy. Currently, your app still contains the following permissions in version code 140 (2.49):

android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
After removing these permissions, you can submit a new release with the APK that does not contain these permissions to replace the current active APKs.

The Play Console may still be prompting you to submit a Permissions Declaration Form if you still have active APKs in different tracks. If you have active APKs with permissions in multiple tracks, you have to submit Permissions Declaration Form and update all active tracks with APKs with the permissions. When updating the last track, the form will not be needed. You can also not include or create an empty release (a release without any APKs) for testing tracks as part of this.

To release a new compliant APK, please follow these steps:

Go to your Play Console.

Select the app.

On the left menu, select Release and choose the track (Production or Testing > Open/Closed/Internal) which includes sensitive permissions.

Click “Create new release” or “Manage Track”.

a. Suggested order (if tracks have non-compliant APKs): Internal track > Closed > Open > Production.
If you are required to complete Permissions Declaration Form while releasing the app, please complete the form according to the following instructions:

a. Choose one core functionality (e.g. Default SMS handler) to make a release with compliant APK. This release may automatically lead to rejection but this will not include the non-compliant APK(s) in the track.
Select Save > Review at the bottom of the page.

Click Start Rollout.

a. Please ensure that the new release is rolled out 100% and completely not including the non-compliant APK.
Go back to step 1 to make another release in the track where non-compliant APK(s) are in active status until there is no active APK with sensitive permissions across tracks.

Thanks for working with us through this process and please let us know if you have any further questions.